# How to use lseek to read the last character of a file

Tags: c++, unix, system-calls

I'm trying to read the characters from a file in reverse order using lseek.

So far, I have:

```
 int finished = 1;
 char temp[1];

    while (finished > 0) {

 lseek(fileID,0,2);

 finished = read(fileID, &temp, 1);

 cout << temp[0];

    }
```

But read always returns 0.

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surely the call to lseek() should be

```
lseek(fileID, -1, SEEK_END);
```

You are seeking to the end of file and you need to be one byte short.

Comment: Watch out for zero-sized files, i.e. check the return value from `lseek` to make sure it didn't fail.